# What does positive dimensional variety mean?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I recently heard the term 'positive dimensional variety'. Does this simply mean that the variety is nonempty and not a point? Or am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: Do you know the definition of dimension?

Comment: the dimension of a variety is the krull dimension of the coordinate ring, right?

Comment: @KReiser so does it mean the variety is not a collection of finitely many points?

Comment: The dimension of a variety is the Krull dimension of the ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ for some point $x \in X$. Thus a positive dimensional variety is a variety $(X, \mathcal{O}_{X})$ such that for all $x \in X$, $\dim(\mathcal{O}_{X,x}) \geq 1$.

Comment: @Geoff isn't this only true for irreducible varieties? I still believe to be correct in saying that a positive dimensional variety is just a variety not consisting of finitely many points

Comment: Spectrum of a dvr has exactly two points, but positive dimensional.

Comment: @Mohan I'm never sure what "variety" exactly means to people, but I don't think that usually counts

Comment: I specifically mean affine or projective varieties. Can someone please confirm that my thought is atleast correct in the classical setup

Comment: Put your definitions in your post (via an [edit]) and maybe there can be constructive dialog here.

Comment: @Geoff What about the generic point in $\operatorname{Spec}(k[x,y])$? The Krull dimension of $k[x,y]_{(0)}$ is 0 since $k[x,y]_{(0)}$ is a field, but $\operatorname{Spec}(k[x,y])$ has dimension 2. I think we need to require that the point is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a variety is zero dimensional if it's a finite set of points (over an algebraically closed field), and positive means at least one-dimensional.